# Combining jQuery tools Overlay and Scrollable/Tabs with direct navigation

Tags: jquery, overlay

Im using jQuery tools overlay to load a page via ajax. I need to be able to pass some parameters to this page when the overlay is opened. The aim is that when the external page is opened it can look at these parameters and then use jquery to display the appropriate information depending on which link was clicked to open the overlay.

There's not really a useful code snippet i can show because im working from the demos on the jquery tools site. the demo in question is this one: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs you should check this out.
http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/creating-ajax-websites-based-on-anchor-navigation/

Allows you to have a URL ending with an anchor like #main, #secondtab or something else and execute specific code for each anchor.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I ended up just using .net in the end but that article looks very useful so i'll bear it in mind. cheers :)